# Trouble with Battleship(Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to make a battleship game in Java where I put in the co-ordinates for the ships and then the opponent(computer) puts in their co-ordinates. Then, both players enter the row/column to select a spot on the map. But then, it crashes.

Here is the code.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class battleShip {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] board = new int[5][5];
    int[][] ships = new int[5][5];
    int[] shoot = new int[5];
int[] shoot2 = new int[4];
    int attempts=0,
        shotHit=0;

    initBoard(board);
initBoard2(board);
    initShips(ships);

    System.out.println();

    do{
        showBoard(board);
    showBoard2(board);
        shoot(shoot);
    shoot2(shoot2);
        attempts++;

        if(hit(shoot,ships)){
            hint(shoot,ships,attempts);
            shotHit++;
        }      
    if(hit2(shoot2,ships)){
            hint2(shoot2,ships,attempts);
            shotHit++;
        }                
        else
            hint(shoot,ships,attempts);
    hint2(shoot2,ships,attempts);

        changeboard(shoot,ships,board);

    changeboard2(shoot2,ships,board);
    }while(shotHit!=4);

    System.out.println("\n\n\nBattleship Java game finished! You hit 4 ships in "+attempts+" attempts");
    showBoard(board);
showBoard2(board);
}

public static void initBoard(int[][] board){
    for(int row=0 ; row < 5 ; row++ )
        for(int column=0 ; column < 5 ; column++ )
            board[row][column]=-1;
}
public static void initBoard2(int[][] board){
    for(int row2=0 ; row2 < 5 ; row2++ )
        for(int column2=0 ; column2 < 5 ; column2++ )
            board[row2][column2]=-1;
}

public static void showBoard(int[][] board){
    System.out.println("\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5");
    System.out.println();

    for(int row=0 ; row < 5 ; row++ ){
        System.out.print((row+1)+"");
        for(int column=0 ; column < 5 ; column++ ){
            if(board[row][column]==-1||board[row][column]==-1||board[row][column]==-3){
                System.out.print("\t"+"~");
            }else if(board[row][column]==0){
                System.out.print("\t"+"*");
            }else if(board[row][column]==1){
                System.out.print("\t"+"X");
            }



        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
public static void showBoard2(int[][] board){
    System.out.println("\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5");
    System.out.println();

    for(int row2=0 ; row2 < 5 ; row2++ ){
        System.out.print((row2+1)+"");
        for(int column2=0 ; column2 < 5 ; column2++ ){
            if(board[row2][column2]==-1||board[row2][column2]==-1||board[row2][column2]==-3){
                System.out.print("\t"+"~");
            }else if(board[row2][column2]==0){
                System.out.print("\t"+"*");
            }else if(board[row2][column2]==1){
                System.out.print("\t"+"X");
            }



        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public static void initShips(int[][] ships){
    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int ship=0 ; ship < 4 ; ship++){
        ships[ship][0]=input.nextInt();
        ships[ship][1]=input.nextInt();
    ships[ship][2]=random.nextInt(4);
        ships[ship][3]=random.nextInt(4);

        //let's check if that shot was already tried 
        //if it was, just finish the do...while when a new pair was randomly selected
        for(int last=0 ; last < ship ; last++){
            if( (ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0])&&(ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1])&&(ships[ship][2] == ships[last][2])&&(ships[ship][3] == ships[last][3]) )
                do{

        ships[ship][2]=random.nextInt(4);
                ships[ship][3]=random.nextInt(4);
                }while( (ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0])&&(ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1])&& (ships[ship][2] == ships[last][2])&&(ships[ship][3] == ships[last][3]) );
        }

    }
}

public static void shoot(int[] shoot){
Random random = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Row: ");
    shoot[0] = input.nextInt();
    shoot[0]--;

    System.out.print("Column: ");
    shoot[1] = input.nextInt();
    shoot[1]--;
}
public static void shoot2(int[] shoot2){
Random random = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Computer turn: ");
    shoot2[2] = random.nextInt(5);
    shoot2[2]--;


    shoot2[3] = random.nextInt(5);
    shoot2[3]--;

}

public static boolean hit(int[] shoot, int[][] ships){

    for(int ship=0 ; ship<ships.length ; ship++){
        if( shoot[0]==ships[ship][0] && shoot[1]==ships[ship][1]){
            System.out.printf("You hit a ship located in (%d,%d)\n",shoot[0]+1,shoot[1]+1);
            return true;
        }
}
return false;
}
public static boolean hit2(int[] shoot2, int[][] ships){

for(int ship=0 ; ship<ships.length ; ship++){
    if( shoot2[2]==ships[ship][2] && shoot2[3]==ships[ship][3]){
            System.out.printf("Computer hit a ship located in (%d,%d)\n",shoot2[2]+1,shoot2[3]+1);
            return true; 
    }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void hint(int[] shoot, int[][] ships, int attempt){
    int row=0,
        column=0;

    for(int line=0 ; line < ships.length ; line++){
        if(ships[line][0]==shoot[0])
            row++;
        if(ships[line][1]==shoot[1])
            column++;

    }

    System.out.printf("\nHint %d: \nRow %d -> %d ships\n" +
                             "Column %d -> %d ships\n",attempt,shoot[0]+1,row,shoot[1]+1,column);
 }
public static void hint2(int[] shoot2, int[][] ships, int attempt){
    int row2=0,
        column2=0;

    for(int line=0 ; line < ships.length ; line++){
    if(ships[line][2]==shoot2[2])
            row2++;
    if(ships[line][3]==shoot2[3])
            column2++;

    }
System.out.printf("\nHint %d: \nRow %d -> %d ships\n" +
                             "Column %d -> %d ships\n",attempt,shoot2[2]+1,row2,shoot2[3]+1,column2);
}

public static void changeboard(int[] shoot, int[][] ships, int[][] board){
    if(hit(shoot,ships))
        board[shoot[0]][shoot[1]]=1;

    else 
        board[shoot[0]][shoot[1]]=0;
}    
public static void changeboard2(int[] shoot2, int[][] ships, int[][] board){   
if(hit2(shoot2,ships))
    board[shoot2[2]][shoot2[3]]=1;
else
    board[shoot2[2]][shoot2[3]]=0;
}
}
```

And this is what happens when I run it in CMD.

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Battleship>javac battleShip.java

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Battleship>java battleShip
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3

         1       2       3       4       5

1       ~       ~       ~       ~       ~
2       ~       ~       ~       ~       ~
3       ~       ~       ~       ~       ~
4       ~       ~       ~       ~       ~
5       ~       ~       ~       ~       ~
        1       2       3       4       5

1       ~       ~       ~       ~       ~
2       ~       ~       ~       ~       ~
3       ~       ~       ~       ~       ~
4       ~       ~       ~       ~       ~
5       ~       ~       ~       ~       ~
Row: 2
Column: 3
Computer turn: You hit a ship located in (2,3)

Hint 1:
Row 2 -> 1 ships
Column 3 -> 1 ships

Hint 1:
Row 2 -> 1 ships
Column 3 -> 1 ships

Hint 1:
Row 4 -> 1 ships
Column 0 -> 0 ships
You hit a ship located in (2,3)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at battleShip.changeboard2(battleShip.java:216)
        at battleShip.main(battleShip.java:41)
    Issue occurs when person selects column or row 0
```

I would really appreciate the help :(

Comment: I am not getting that error, using your same input. It seemingly works.

Comment: I think it only happens when I use the 1 co-ordinate

Comment: It would be very helpful to know exactly how to cause this error. The printout of your output is not clear, as far as what you need to enter where. If we can't reproduce your problem, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int nextInt(int n)
```

Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

```
public static void shoot2(int[] shoot2){
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.print("Computer turn: ");
    shoot2[2] = random.nextInt(5);
    shoot2[3] = random.nextInt(5);
}
```